# Laravel with() together Table or Variable Name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I was reading a blog related [Repository Pattern](https://itnext.io/repository-design-pattern-done-right-in-laravel-d177b5fa75d4). I saw use of **withBlogs** method.

```
public function index()
{
    $blogs = $this->blogRepository->all();

    return view('blog')->withBlogs($blogs);
}
```

I never see something like this before. What is the purpose of it or what it's doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is laravel's magic methods

you can name the method anything you want with with() in laravel

let me explain you by example, the following code you write in your controller method

```
return view('index')->withName('Name')->withFullName('Full Name')->withaddress('Your address')->withcountryName('CountryName');
```

then you can access the values in view explained below

```
withName('Name') in view it becomes $name
withFullName('Full Name') in view it becomes $fullName
withaddress('Your address') in view it becomes $address
withcountryName('CountryName') in view it becomes $countryName
```

Comment: withFullName('Full Name') here "Full Name", is it variable?

Comment: withFullName("Full Name") in this you can access value using $fullName which holds the value "Full Name" like $fullName = "Full Name" whatever you provide in ( ) becomes the value of $fullName variable

Comment: I wanted to know what could be the data source of 'Full Name'? In case of $blog, it was retrieve data through eloquent by Repository.

Comment: 'Full Name' should not have space, I guess... I'm confused there

Comment: 'Full Name' is the value of $fullName, it is string value and It can be anything string or variable or an object of a class

Comment: For someone from future, look into documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#basic-usage

Answer (score 2):

It is used for passing data into views. The `with` method returns an instance of the view object so that you can continue chaining methods before returning the view. All of the syntax below archives the same thing:

```php
return view('blog')->withBlogs($blogs);

return view('blog')->with('blogs', $blogs);

return view('blog')->with(compact('blogs'));

return view('blog', compact('blogs'));
```

Comment: It was helpful though